# how to write HttpRequest with "get" Method

Tags: java, google-http-client

I'm using **com.google.api.client.http**

I want to send some request with this package.

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(new HttpTransport(),"GET");
```

But the HttpTransport in the package is abstract ,so it means I need to implement this class?

Is there anyone who can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to implement this class if the library supplies some concrete classes inheriting from this abstract class(unless none of them fits your needs). For example, `ApacheHttpTransport`, `NetHttpTransport` and `UrlFetchTransport`.

Comment: I see ! But what's the difference between them? Are they thread-safe?

Comment: Yes, `HttpTransport` doc says: Implementation is thread-safe, and sub-classes must be thread-safe